# Do I have to compile Unreal 4's source myself in order to make games with it?

Tags: unreal

Now I understand the need for this if people want to make modifications to the engine itself, but if I want to use the engine as is and just program games with it, do I need to do all this?

I figured I needed to build the Engine because a UE4 programming tutorial said "I assume you have already downloaded the engine source from GitHub and compiled it in VS2013", nobody says why, nobody clearly states whether or not this is required to make a game in C++ using Unreal Engine 4.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you going to run your game without a compiled engine? Or are there precompiled versions available for download?

Comment: @PaulG UE4 is not open source, right? What source you are talking about?

Comment: @bummzack using scripting this used to be possible. However, I do not know exactly how Kismet comes into play here.

Comment: At first, I didn't download the source and intellisense was working too slow or wasn't working at all. Then I heard downloading and compiling the source would be a good idea to speed up intellisense; they say it makes a great difference. I haven't tried it yet; it's still compiling :}

Comment: @Narek ? What do you think github is... A binary publication tool? To be specific it's not open source, not in the sense that the source may not be redistributed but it; you can however download the source.

Comment: @PaulG I strongly recommend to reword the question to: Do I need to compile the Unreal 4 source myself in order to make games?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to build the the engine / editor yourself. There are several iterations of the engine (current is 4.4), since they released it earlier this year (4.0), are you sure that you used the same one as in the tutorial? You can select the version you want to use in the launcher. 
The only source you have to build are your own classes, you want to add to the project.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the monthly subscription option, you are given access to the private GitHub repository and must compile the editor before you can use it. The wiki has an [excellent walkthrough](http://wiki.unrealengine.com/GitHub_Setup) of the current process.

It's getting easier - the upcoming 4.6 release has a setup script that does everything for you in one step - but subscribers don't get prepackaged binaries yet.

It is my understanding that a custom license may give you access to pre-built binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Is that possible duplicate of your [original post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199863/can-i-write-software-using-unreal-engine-4-without-compiling-unreal-engine-4-fro/26503823#26503823)?

But I want to give to you the same answer here:

> No you dont need the whole engine. There is a difference between the
>   code which builds the editor and the code which builds your game. If
>   you only want to program your game you should create a new "code
>   project" and modify the code you're getting after creating the new
>   project.